# How to calculate difference between 2 data points in grafana

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana

This graph is giving me total bytes website has accepted i want to find instant value at that time for that i've to minus two data points can anyone help?
(sum(windows_iis_received_bytes_total{instance=~"ServerName",site="WebSiteName"} + windows_iis_sent_bytes_total{instance=~"ServerName",site="WebSiteName"} ) )

[image]

Comment: did you tried using a transformation?

Comment: Have you considered using one of `rate`,`irate`,`increase` or `deriv`,`delta` promQL functions?